# Cambiar el nombre de una imagen antes o despues de guardarla

Tags: java, android, imagen

estoy haciendo una app en android studio, y necesitaria cambiar el nombre de una imagen antes de guardarla. Detallo más, primero subo una imagen desde la memoria de mi movil, la cambio por la que viene puesta por defecto y despues la guardo, pero se guarda con el nombre que tuviera dicha imagen. Necesitaría cambiar ese nombre de esa nueva imagen antes o despues de guardarla llamandose igual que la que había, pero en una carpeta distinta.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.carpeta_acciones);

        imagen = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.abrazar);
        imagen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openGallery();
            }
        });
    }

    private void openGallery() {
        Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        gallery.setType("image/*");
        if (gallery.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(gallery, REQUEST_IMAGE_GET);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                imageUri = data.getData();
                dir = new File(getFilesDir(), nombreCarpeta);

            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }

            //file = new File(dir, imagen + ".png");
            imagen.setImageURI(imageUri);
            imagen.buildDrawingCache();

            imgUri = imageUri.toString();
            //imagen.buildDrawingCache();
           // bmp = imagen.getDrawingCache();
            cr= this.getContentResolver();
            try {
               //bmap =  MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(imgUri);
                bmap=android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr,imageUri);

            }catch(IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
               /* Bitmap imag = ((BitmapDrawable)imagen.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                String ruta = guardarImagen(getApplicationContext(), "abrazar", imag);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ruta, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/

            guardarImagen(contexto,"abrazar",bmap);
        }

    }


    private String guardarImagen (Context context,String nombre, Bitmap bmap){

        file = new File(dir,bmap + ".png");
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ImageView imageView;
        Bitmap bmp;

        try{

            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(contexto, "¡No se ha podido guardar la imagen!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(contexto, "¡No se ha podido guardar la imagen!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

Si me puedierais ayudar os lo agradecería estoy atascada. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El nombre lo debes asignar aquí, donde defines la ruta y el nombre del archivo:

```
private String guardarImagen (Context context,String nombre, Bitmap bmap){

    //file = new File(dir,bmap + ".png"); //*Incorrecto.
      file = new File(dir,nombre + ".png"); //*Correcto.
...
...
```

Esto lo puedes verificar en la [documentación para File()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: Gracias, lo probaré, pensé que así no me cogería la foto. Muchas gracias

Comment: Creo que si ha funcionado, aunque no lo sé porque no encuentro carpeta en la memoria interna de mi movil para ver si dicha foto está o no. Pero gracias.

Comment: Si se guardan en la memoria interna de tu dispositivo no se puede visualizar mediante File explorer, a menos que tengas permisos ROOT en tu dispositivo.